# How to search a data frame for multiple strings and pull different column contents depending on string column and row

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (approx. 500,000 x 5,000) where I need to do the following:

1. Search the entire dataset for a number of different strings (up to 30 at a time).
2. Depending on the column that the string occurs in, to retrieve information from another column within the same row. The columns are linked, so column `V1` is linked to `D1` and `V2` to `D2`. Therefore, if a string is identified in, for example, `V2` row 3, I would like to extract the value in `D2` row 3.
3. The value from a fixed column of the same row (in my case `ID`) should also be extracted.

I have already been able to use `which` to identify the row and column numbers for each of the strings but have been unable to work out the next step to extract additional column values depending on the results of the search.

An example `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:5,
                 "V1" = c("A1", "A2", "A1", "A3", "A4"),
                 "V2" = c("A6", "NA", "A3", "A2", "A1"),
                 "D1" = c("B3", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B5"),
                 "D2" = c("B8", "NA", "B2", "B6", "B2"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

ID V1 V2 D1 D2
1  A1 A6 B3 B8   
2  A2 NA B3 NA   
3  A1 A3 B2 B2 
4  A3 A2 B1 B6 
5  A4 A1 B5 B2
```

When the code is run to search for "A1", it retrieves the corresponding `ID` and relevant `D` variable in a data frame or list format:

```
 ID: 1, D1: B3
 ID: 3, D1: B2
 ID: 5, D2: B2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, we can separate `"V"` and `"D"` cols, find occurrence of `"A1"` from `V_cols` get corresponding `ID` and since `V_cols` and `D_cols` are linked we can get corresponding values from `D_cols` using `which` with row and column index.

```
V_cols <- grep("^V", names(df), value = TRUE)
D_cols <- grep("^D", names(df), value = TRUE)

mat <- which(df[V_cols] == "A1", arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(ID = df$ID[mat[, 1]], D_var = df[D_cols][mat], D_col = D_cols[mat[, 2]])

#  ID D_var D_col
#1  1    B3    D1
#2  3    B2    D1
#3  5    B2    D2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df_melted <- melt(df, id.vars = "ID",  measure.vars = patterns(V = '^V', D = '^D'))
df_melted 
#     ID variable  V  D
#  1:  1        1 A1 B3
#  2:  2        1 A2 B3
#  3:  3        1 A1 B2
#  4:  4        1 A3 B1
#  5:  5        1 A4 B5
#  6:  1        2 A6 B8
#  7:  2        2 NA NA
#  8:  3        2 A3 B2
#  9:  4        2 A2 B6
# 10:  5        2 A1 B2

strings <- c("A1")
df_melted[V %chin% strings, paste0('ID: ', ID, ', D', variable, ": ", D)]
# "ID: 1, D1: B3" "ID: 3, D1: B2" "ID: 5, D2: B2"
```